# Generating a random number without duplicates on blog comment

Tags: 7, theming, comments

A section of my site is a blog where I allow comments. Each comment has a thumbnail associated with it. If the commenter is a user, then their profile photo is used. If they are anonymous I have a pre-determined photo in place. I want to be able to randomly generate a thumbnail for these anonymous users, but also have no duplicates.

I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537862/generating-a-random-number-without-duplication-issue#24537924) and now have a random thumbnail being generated, but the problem is that there are still duplicates. And it looks like because the comment.tpl.php file is being read on each comment that the random numbers are not being remembered.

How can Drupal remember the number so that it doesn't use it again?

My Code:

```
$numbers = range(0, 19);
shuffle($numbers);

print "<div id='commenter-picture'>";
print "<img src='member_default_" . array_pop($numbers) . ".png' />";
print "</div>";
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Haven't tested this, but I think this should work. Remove your first two lines of code and place the following in your theme's `template.php` file (replace MYTHEME with the machine name of your theme):

`function MYTHEME_preprocess_comment(&$vars){
    $max = 19;
    $numbers =  $_SESSION['MYTHEME_comment_numbers'] ?: range(0, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    $vars['number'] = array_pop($numbers);
    $_SESSION['MYTHEME_comment_numbers'] = count($numbers) ? $numbers : range(0, $max);
}`

This makes available a $number variable inside your comment.tpl.php file.

Then, replace your last three lines inside comment.tpl.php with:

```
print "<div id='commenter-picture'>";
print "<img src='member_default_" . $number . ".png' />";
print "</div>";
```

This will remove already used numbers from your $numbers array until there's none left, and then reset to use the full array again.

Comment: Thanks @olyN. I am getting an error when trying to run this. Can I run this as it shows or do I need to rename the 'MYMODULE' variable? I am new to PHP so this is a bit over my head. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No worries. Are you adding this into a template file? What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Well I get the traditional white screen with no CSS styling on the page. I am placing this into my comment.tpl.php template file.

Comment: OK, fixed, I've edited the answer. You should replace MYTHEME with the machine name of your theme. It will probably work anyway, but it's good to use naming conventions. :)

Comment: The page keeps crashing on this line: $numbers = array_values(array_diff($numbers, $already_used);

Comment: There's a missing final parenthesis in that. In my updated answer it's: $numbers = array_values(array_diff($numbers, $already_used));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15518/discussion-between-olyn-and-dan).

Comment: I'm sorry I downvoted this answer because of the use of variable_set(). A call to variable_set in a comment.tpl.php file won't get executed everytime due to caching, but when it does, it clears the variable cache which can result in severe performance problems.

Comment: @Ayesh it *will* be called every time, modulo page caching, which is fine, but you're right about the performance hit. I guess the array can just as well be stored in the session variable. I would probably have done this in a preprocess hook rather than in a template. I was just trying to get something that would work quickly. I'll update the answer with that later.

Comment: @AyeshK I've updated the answer again, this time without invoking variable_set.